# Set the destination path for glob match on archiverjs

Tags: node.js, archiverjs

I've been working with the `archiverjs` node module and it works great. I'd now like to use a glob match to determine which files to zip but I also want to set the destination path in the zip just like you can with the `destPath` option in the [directory method](https://archiverjs.com/docs/Archiver.html#directory). I'm wondering if there's an option or something that will accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed no one try to answer this question for a long time.

I confronted the same problem when using the [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) node module. I wanted to append files from a glob pattern and also set the destination path for them instead of the root directory.

Then I found an issue on archiver github [#229](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver/issues/229) . Surprisingly, the prefix option cleared my problem.

```
archive.glob('file*.txt', {cwd: source_dir}, {prefix: destination_dir});
```

Hope it could help someone.

Best regards,